# How to create a custom Raspberry Pi Ubuntu server image?

Tags: raspberrypi

I'd like to create my own Raspberry Pi 4 image like https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.1/release/ubuntu-20.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz

Where is the code to build the preinstalled server arm 64 image?

How do you customize the image?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi site offers [step-by-step instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) on image building. This should give you a start 

Comment: Thanks @Matigo. Is there any instruction for Ubuntu image?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build preinstalled Ubuntu server image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1350211/how-to-build-preinstalled-ubuntu-server-image)