# How to build preinstalled Ubuntu server image?

Tags: server, raspberrypi, disk-image, preinstallation

There are Preinstalled Ubuntu server image for Raspberry Pi on https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/focal/release/:

Where can I find the build scripts to build such image?

[image]

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous question: [How to create a custom Raspberry Pi Ubuntu server image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312355/how-to-create-a-custom-raspberry-pi-ubuntu-server-image).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full understanding, as Canonical don't seem to care about documenting anything that's not a press release for Snap or Core anymore.

But starting to piece things together, I think it's a combination of [ubuntu-image](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/ubuntu-image.1.html) with  the `classic` branch of [snapcore/pi-gadget](https://github.com/snapcore/pi-gadget/tree/classic). (so it looks like the build system uses `snap`, but still builds a `classic` based image)